# how to display delete cancel popup when clicking a button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

can anybody help me for bring this View whenn clicking a button[image]

Comment: You can use ActionSheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Title You want to give";        //Action Sheet Title
NSString *destructiveTitle = nil;                       //Action Sheet Button Titles
NSString *firstButtonTitle = @"Delete Drafts";               //Action Sheet 1st Button Title
NSString *secondButtonTitle = @"Save Drafts";     //Action Sheet 2nd Button Title
NSString *cancelTitle = @"Cancel";               //Action Sheet Cancel Button Title

UIActionSheet *myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                     delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveTitle
                                     otherButtonTitles:firstButtonTitle,secondButtonTitle, nil];

[myActionSheet showInView:self.view.parentViewController.view];
```